SU(3) Generators Expressed Using Bivectors in Geometric Algebra 3+1D
I am studying the SU(3) group and its generators in the context of geometric algebra. I understand that the SU(3) group has 8 generators, usually denoted as $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_8$. I am interested in expressing these generators using only bivectors in geometric algebra 3+1D.
Given the basis vectors ${\gamma_0, \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3}$ of GA 3+1D, satisfying:
$\gamma_\mu^2 = -1$ for $\mu = 0$, and $\gamma_\mu^2 = 1$ for $\mu = 1, 2, 3$
How can I express the 8 generators of SU(3) using only the bivectors $\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu$ (where $\mu, \nu = 0, 1, 2, 3$)?
I would appreciate if someone could provide the explicit expressions for the generators $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_8$ in terms of these bivectors and explain how these generators satisfy the SU(3) commutation relations:
$$[\lambda_i, \lambda_j] = i f_{ijk} \lambda_k$$
where $f_{ijk}$ are the structure constants of SU(3), and the indices i, j, k run from 1 to 8.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

I think you have something confused. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \cong \bigwedge^2\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ so there is no reason for the latter to be represented by bivectors. You could try to embed $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ in $\mathfrak{su}(4) \cong \mathfrak{so}(6) \cong \bigwedge^2\mathbb{R}^{6}$ but there would be a choice to make there. I'm not sure all such embeddings would even be isomorphic.

@Callum Well you can write SU(2) as $exp(A\gamma_1\gamma_2+B\gamma_1\gamma_3+C\gamma_2\gamma_3)$. There has to be a way to do so with SU(3) as well, no? It wouldn't be an isomorphism, but this is fine. I just want to write SU(3) using elements of GA(3,1).

@Callum What about this?
$$
λ₁ = e₁e₂\
λ₂ = e₂e₃\
λ₃ = -e₃e₁\
λ₄ = e₃e₀\
λ₅ = -e₁e₀\
λ₆ = e₂e₀\
λ₇ = (e₁e₂ - e₃e₀) / √2\
λ₈ = (e₁e₂ + e₂e₃ + e₃e₁) / √3
$$

Why would it working for $SU(2)$ imply that it works for $SU(3)$? $\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \cong \mathfrak{sl}_2 = \mathfrak{su}(2)^\mathbb{C}$ is why this works for $SU(2)$ but this is an "exceptional isomorphism". That is, it is not a general pattern. The real nail in the coffin though is that $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ is only 6-dimensional while $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is 8-dimensional

@Callum what about page 12 https://www.academia.edu/48531053/Space_time_structure_of_weak_and_electromagnetic_interactions This author seems pretty confident in his table.

His table is the action of the generators on the space $\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^3$ which is quite different to what you have asked. If you have a representation on a vector space $V$ you can always derive a representation on $\bigwedge^2 V$ but that is not the same as finding the Lie algebra inside $\bigwedge^2 V$  (or in some entirely different $\bigwedge^2 W$ as you are suggesting)
